# How to define qualified exports to unknown modules?

Tags: java, maven, java-module

I have a Maven project with two Maven modules `A` and `B`. `A` contains the following Java module definition:

```
module A {
    exports internal.util to B;
    exports external.A;
}
```

`B` contains the following Java module definition:

```
module B {
    requires A;

    exports external.B;
}
```

When I build the project, I get an error:

```
[WARNING] module-info.java:[16,106] module not found: B
```

Module `B` exists but because Module `A` is compiled before `B` and does not depend on it, the compiler has no way of knowing that. Because I configured the compiler to treat warnings as errors (`-Werror`), the build fails.

Seeing as I want to keep treating warnings as errors, what is the best way to resolve this problem?

- Is there a way to hint to the compiler that this module will be declared in the future?
- Is there a way to suppress all warnings of this type?

Comment: I assume you have two modules which contain the modules A and B? and not a single maven project which contains two modules? Maybe I misunderstand a thing here?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a Maven project. That project contains two Maven modules. Each Maven module exports a Java module having the same name.

Comment: It is not valid to have two Java modules with the same name (JPMS)...Java module names must be unique...

Comment: @Gili Do you mean to say, exporting to a module that doesn't even exist?

Comment: @khmarbaise That's not what I meant. See the updated question.

Comment: @nullpointer Module `B` exists but because Module `A` is compiled before `B` and does not depend on it, the compiler has no way of knowing that. See the updated question.

Comment: You have to define a dependency between the modules on the Maven level which means add a dependency in your pom so Maven takes care of the build order. This requires to have them within a multi module build which would make sense....

Comment: @khmarbaise Ugh, I'm so sorry but I forgot one more thing. `A` exports to `B` and `B` depends on `A` (I've updated the question accordingly). If I declare that `A` depend on `B` in the pom file Maven complains about a circular dependency because according to the POM `A` depends on `B` and `B` depends on `A`.

Comment: Can you create an example project which shows this setup...

Comment: @khmarbaise Here you go: https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/qualified-exports-testcase

Comment: Do you have a git url for it? I don't have mercurial installed?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't use git outside of work sorry. You can download a snapshot from https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/qualified-exports-testcase/downloads/

Comment: @khmarbaise I ended up filing this bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround by scanning through the JDK 11 source-code: `-Xlint:-module`. I am still open to a better solution if someone finds one.

**UPDATE**: An alternative is to use `--module-source-path` as demonstrated by https://stackoverflow.com/a/53717183/14731

Thank you Alan Bateman for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 0):

As I could infer from the question, your scenario is such that both the module `A` and `B` co-exists and the module `A` does not depend on the module `B`.

From a module system prospect, since `A` makes a qualified export to the module `B`, a warning is thrown if the module `B` is *not resolved on the modulepath* while you build `A`.

On IntelliJ-IDEA I could fix such an issue by adding a dependency of module `B` to the module `A` without any declaration changes. Though using the Maven framework, I couldn't imagine something without a cyclic dependency here, maybe [the suggestion by khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670052/how-to-define-qualified-exports-to-unknown-modules?noredirect=1#comment94206548_53670052) could help.

***Note***:  An alternate way to fix this though could also be to disable such warnings using the command-line arg :

<strike>-Xlint:-exports</strike>

Or as [Alan points out for correction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670052/how-to-define-qualified-exports-to-unknown-modules#comment94209011_53674956)

```
-Xlint:-module
```

Thinking out loud, that would be since, *the warning is a result of a qualified export, but **about a module not found.***

***Useful***: You could find the details over these command line args [with javac command.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53679331/1746118)

Comment: I forgot to mention (I've updated the question) that `B` depends on `A`. I want `A` to export to `B` without depending on it because if I declare a dependency Maven complains about a circular dependency between `A` and `B`. I tried `-Xlint:-exports` but it did not suppress the warning.

Comment: `-Xlint:-module` is what you need here.

Comment: @AlanBateman Is there a better way to resolve this warning, or is suppressing it the right way to go in this case?

Comment: Use --module-source-path to make B observable when compiling A, or compile A with -Xlint:-module. I think they are your only options.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thanks. On the other hand, I doubt `--module-source-path` could be a safe option to use via maven..(thinking about what if the path of such a module changes?)

Comment: @nullpointer `javac --module-source-path modules//\*/src/main/java -m A` should do it. The "*" stands in for the module name.

Comment: @AlanBateman I had read about the command and its usage. I was thinking out more from the perspective of using it in maven. There is an option of adding command line args into `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration. But what if the path I specify today might not have module B in it tomorrow. Would it be safe to add such an arg, would it fail the maven build or what should ideally be expected remains as the question to me.