# How to figure out which Xlint option corresponds to a compiler warning?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-warnings, lint, java-11

My software builds use `-Xlint -Werror` so I routinely run across compiler warnings that break my build. Every once in a while I run across a warning that I need to suppress, but it's always difficult to figure out which `Xlint` option suppresses the warning I am seeing.

I'll give you a concrete example. I recently ran across:

```
[WARNING] module-info.java:[16,106] module not found: 
    org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.guava
```

I searched the JDK 11 source-code and discovered this warning message declared at `/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/resources/compiler.properties` as:

```
# 0: symbol
compiler.err.module.not.found=\
    module not found: {0}
```

Now, it turns out that this is suppressed by `-Xlint:-module` but that's not obvious from the documentation. `-Xlint:-export` could made sense as well. I've also run across warnings in the past that couldn't be suppressed at all (these were subsequently fixed).

Instead of resorting to trial and error, **is there a deterministic way to figure out which `Xlint` option corresponds to each warning message**? Is there some sort of mapping file somewhere in the JDK source codes?

**UPDATE**: I am using Maven 3.6.0, maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.0, JDK 11.0.1

Comment: There’s always the [javac documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-C2076F46-1200-4082-9634-06E7F4851EEA).

Comment: Which compiler is still? Asking because with javac then the warning would be "[module] module not found: ..." and "[module]" gives you the clue that -Xlint:-module may suppress it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @AlanBateman You're right. Maven is at fault. I will post an answer with more details below.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do that, if somehow you're not able to access the [online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9) could be using the command

```
javac --help-extra
```

This would list out the possible warnings that you could enable/disable. For example from ***`javac 12-ea`*** :

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I don't think this is good enough because some errors (e.g. the one mentioned in the question) could belong to multiple options. In other cases (no concrete examples come to mind at the moment) I remember it wasn't obvious which of the above should apply.

Comment: @Gili I would agree that this is not an absolute way of determining which amongst two options should be chosen. But on the other hand, it definitely does gives an insight into how warnings could be categorised.

Answer (score 2):

Alan Bateman pointed me in the right direction. It seems that the maven-compiler-plugin suppressing vital information. Here is the output from javac 11.0.1:

```
C:\Users\Gili\Documents\requirements\java\src\main\java\module-info.java:16: warning: [module] module not found: org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.guava
        exports org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.java.internal.impl to org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.guava;
```

Here is the corresponding output from maven-compiler-plugin:

```
[WARNING] /C:/Users/Gili/Documents/requirements/java/src/main/java/module-info.java:[16,106] module not found: org.bitbucket.cowwoc.requirements.guava
```

`javac` mentions `[module]` at the beginning of the warning, indicating that `-Xlint:-module` will suppress this warning.

I filed a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-367