# Unable to resolve module using --module-source-path

Tags: java, maven, java-module

Following up on [How to define qualified exports to unknown modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53670052/14731) I've posted a [testcase](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/qualified-exports-testcase/downloads/qualified-exports-module-source-path.zip) with two modules: `core` and `plugin`.

`core` tries to expose a package to `plugin` using qualified exports but the compiler complains that `plugin` does not exist. Following up on Alan Bateman's recommendation, I tried adding `--module-source-path <path-of-plugin> --module plugin` pointing from `core` to `plugin` but the compiler complains:

```
module plugin not found in source path
```

Why isn't the compiler able to find module `plugin`?

Comment: Just to clarify this is `maven-compiler-plugin` complaining or `javac`?

Comment: @nullpointer Both give the same error. I get this same error running `javac` directly. You can run `mvn clean install -X` to get the `javac` command-line being invoked, then run it manually.

Comment: Would be good to share the complete `javac` command here as well. It would bring clarity if something might be missing in the actual use case you're driving.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out through trial and error.

1. Use `--module-source-path ${project.basedir}/../*/src/main/java` to make sure the compiler can see the source-code of both modules.
2. Use `--module core` to make sure that the compiler only builds `core` in spite of seeing all modules.
3. Tell `maven-jar-plugin` to package classes from `classes/${module.name}` instead of just `classes` because `module-source-path` causes the output to be prefixed by the module name. I have not found a way to disable this prefix.

The fixed code can be found at https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/qualified-exports-testcase/

**Caveat**: This technique only works if the module directory name (the component resolved by `*`) matches the Java module name. In this particular example the module `core` had its sources in directory `core/src/main/java`. If, on the other hand, the directory name was `core` but the corresponding Java module was `org.bitbucket.core` then the compilation would fail with `module org.bitbucket.core not found in module source path`.